# Site gets slow page loading both frontend and backend in magento2.3.3

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.3

The backend of Magento ranges between slow and super slow when editing.. opening an item for changes and saving an item following editing. Sometimes it can take minutes! It has always been slow.
The issue with the page slow to fully open, It takes around 6 seconds to load the page image and the image flash at 6 seconds.

The cart takes more than 5 seconds to download.

Answer (score 2):

Slowness of Site depends on the Work has been done on Magento.

Following are the steps you can do to increase the site speed -

1. Enable JS and CSS Minify
2. Enable Caching
3. Enable the profiler to check the exact files and event which are taking time and then debug the code -

Use Command to enable Profiler - **php bin/magento dev:profiler:enable**

Once you enable the Profiler then see the events at the below table of pages.